# Summation using for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to find the total from the input field and set the total value to the particular text field.
Here is my Html:

```
 <table id="table" border="1">

 <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td colspan="4">Injuried</td>
     <td colspan="4">Killed</td>
     <td colspan="4">Died</td>
 </tr>
<tr>
     <td></td>
    <td>adult</td>
     <td>young</td>
     <td>children</td>
     <td>total</td>
    <td>adult</td>
     <td>young</td>
     <td>children</td>
     <td>total</td>
    <td>adult</td>
     <td>young</td>
     <td>children</td>
     <td>total</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>number</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="5" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="5"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="5"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="5"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="5"/></td>
     <td><input type="text" size="5"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="5"/></td>
     <td><input type="text"size="5" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="5"/></td>
     <td><input type="text" size="5"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="5"/></td>
     <td><input type="text" size="5"/></td>

</tr>
<tr>
     <td>number</td>
    <td><input type="text" size="5" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="5"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="5"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="5"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="5"/></td>
     <td><input type="text" size="5"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="5"/></td>
     <td><input type="text"size="5" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="5"/></td>
     <td><input type="text" size="5"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" size="5"/></td>
     <td><input type="text" size="5"/></td>

</tr>
</table>
```

Here I want to add each adult,young,children field in each row and set the value to the corresponded total column.I used for loop for this purpose. But It Shows some error while adding.
Here is my sample code.
http://jsfiddle.net/3gxnya5a/

Comment: can you please explain , how you want the output the total of separate section should be in that category total.?

Comment: Are you creating the rows of table dynamically or not??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple loop like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#table').on('keyup', 'input', function () {

        //loop through each 4th td in each rows as they are the sum elements
        $("#table tr").slice(2).find("td:nth-child(4n + 1)").each(function () {
            var sum = 0;
            //add up the previous 4 values
            $(this).prevAll(':lt(3)').find('input').each(function () {
                sum += (+this.value || 0)
            });
            $(this).find('input').val(sum)
        })
    })
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#table').on('keyup', 'input', function() {

    $("#table tr").slice(2).find("td:nth-child(4n + 1)").each(function() {
      var sum = 0;
      $(this).prevAll(':lt(3)').find('input').each(function() {
        sum += (+this.value || 0)
      });
      $(this).find('input').val(sum)
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td colspan="4">Injuried</td>
    <td colspan="4">Killed</td>
    <td colspan="4">Died</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>adult</td>
    <td>young</td>
    <td>children</td>
    <td>total</td>
    <td>adult</td>
    <td>young</td>
    <td>children</td>
    <td>total</td>
    <td>adult</td>
    <td>young</td>
    <td>children</td>
    <td>total</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>number</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" size="5" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" size="5" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" size="5" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" size="5" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" size="5" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" size="5" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" size="5" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" size="5" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" size="5" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" size="5" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" size="5" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" size="5" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>number</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" size="5" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" size="5" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" size="5" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" size="5" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" size="5" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" size="5" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" size="5" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" size="5" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" size="5" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" size="5" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" size="5" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" size="5" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Already answered, but I felt worth adding an alternative.

If you add attributes to the columns you want to add, your code won't / is less likely to break when you add columns/move them around, eg:

```
<table id='theTable'>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" size="5" class='data-add' /></td>
      <td><input type="text" size="5" class='data-add' /></td>
      <td><input type="text" size="5" /></td>
      <td><input type="text" size="5" class='data-total'/></td>
```

then

```
$("#theTable>tbody>tr").each(function() {
    var sum = 0;
    $(".data-add", this).each(function() {
        sum += (+this.value || 0);  // stolen from Arun to ignore invalid values etc
    });
    $(".data-total", this).val(sum);
});
```